# How to Aggregate in MongoDB by employee & month, & day?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am using MongoDB and need to build a report based on data I have,
a document looks as follows:

```
{
    "_id": {"$oid": "60f66d177bb6ea476309b58b"},
    "__v": 0,
    "employeeUserName": "mat@gmail.com",
    "ended_at": {"$date": "2021-04-20T16:01:00.000Z"},
    "started_at": {"$date": "2021-04-20T09:12:00.000Z"},
    "totalHr": 6.816666666666666
}
```

What i would like to do is to get a report per `employee` per month per day.
For each day i should sum `totalHr`, then for each month i need to sum total for all days in month.

so the expected output should kindly look like this:

```
    [{
  employee:"a",
  months:[
    {
      number: 7,
      totalforMonth: 24,
      days:[
        
        {
          day: 21,
          totalHr: 8
        },
         {
          day: 22,
          totalHr: 8
        },
         {
          day: 23,
          totalHr: 8
        }
        ]
    },
    {
      number: 4,
      totalforMonth: 45,
      days:[
        
        {
          day: 21,
          totalHr: 13
        },
         {
          day: 22,
          totalHr: 13
        },
         {
          day: 23,
          totalHr: 19
        }
        ]
    }
    
    ]
},
{
    employee:"b",
  months:[
    {
      number: 7,
      totalforMonth:27 ,
      days:[
        
        {
          day: 21,
          totalHr: 5
        },
         {
          day: 22,
          totalHr: 10
        },
         {
          day: 23,
          totalHr: 12
        }
        ]
    }]
}
]
```

But for the following query:

```
    db.employee_shifts.aggregate([
    {
    $group:{
    _id:{employee: "$employeeUserName", month:{$month:"$started_at"},day:{$dayOfMonth:"$started_at"}},
    totalHrPerDay: {$sum:"$totalHr"},
    }
    },
    {
    $group:{
    _id: {employee:"$_id.employee"},
    months:{"$addToSet":{month:"$_id.month",days:{totalForDay:"$totalHrPerDay", day:"$_id.day"}}},
    }
    },
    {
    $project: {
            employee: "$_id.employee",
            months:"$months",
            _id:false
        }
    }

])
```

I get:

```
  [
  {
    "employee": "mat@gmail.com",
    "months": [
      {
        "month": 6,
        "days": {
          "totalForDay": 6.816666666666666,
          "day": 24
        }
      },
      {
        "month": 4,
        "days": {
          "totalForDay": 9.633333333333333,
          "day": 20
        }
      },
      {
        "month": 7,
        "days": {
          "totalForDay": 6.816666666666666,
          "day": 16
        }
      },
      {
        "month": 4,
        "days": {
          "totalForDay": 6.816666666666666,
          "day": 21
        }
      },
      {
        "month": 7,
        "days": {
          "totalForDay": 6.816666666666666,
          "day": 17
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "employee": "matant@gmail.com",
    "months": [
      {
        "month": 6,
        "days": {
          "totalForDay": 6.816666666666666,
          "day": 23
        }
      },
      {
        "month": 4,
        "days": {
          "totalForDay": 6.816666666666666,
          "day": 21
        }
      },
      {
        "month": 6,
        "days": {
          "totalForDay": 6.816666666666666,
          "day": 22
        }
      },
      {
        "month": 4,
        "days": {
          "totalForDay": 6.816666666666666,
          "day": 19
        }
      },
      {
        "month": 5,
        "days": {
          "totalForDay": 6.816666666666666,
          "day": 21
        }
      },
      {
        "month": 6,
        "days": {
          "totalForDay": 6.816666666666666,
          "day": 24
        }
      },
      {
        "month": 5,
        "days": {
          "totalForDay": 6.816666666666666,
          "day": 22
        }
      },
      {
        "month": 4,
        "days": {
          "totalForDay": 6.816666666666666,
          "day": 20
        }
      },
      {
        "month": 7,
        "days": {
          "totalForDay": 6.816666666666666,
          "day": 17
        }
      },
      {
        "month": 7,
        "days": {
          "totalForDay": 6.816666666666666,
          "day": 16
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

looks like i am not grouping the month correctly for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `$group` by `employee`, `day`, `month` and `year`, get total hours sum that is daily
- `$group` by `employee`, `month` and `year`, construct the array of days and count total hours for `month`
- `$group` by `employee` only and construct the array of `months`

```
db.employee_shifts.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        employee: "$employeeUserName",
        day: { $dayOfMonth: "$started_at" },
        month: { $month: "$started_at" },
        year: { $year: "$started_at" }
      },
      totalHr: { $sum: "$totalHr" }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        employee: "$_id.employee",
        month: "$_id.month",
        year: "$_id.year"
      },
      days: {
        $push: {
          day: "$_id.day",
          totalHr: "$totalHr"
        }
      },
      totalHr: { $sum: "$totalHr" }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.employee",
      months: {
        $push: {
          number: "$_id.month",
          days: "$days",
          totalforMonth: "$totalHr"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      employee: "$_id",
      months: 1
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VgyZHJqa1Mw)

Comment: This solution looks better than my one where I do `{ $push: "$$ROOT" }` and `$map` afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

A working solution is this one:

```
db.employee_shifts.aggregate([
   {
      $group: {
         _id: {
            employee: "$employeeUserName",
            year: { $year: "$started_at" },
            month: { $month: "$started_at" },
            day: { $dayOfMonth: "$started_at" }
         },
         totalHrPerDay: { $sum: "$totalHr" }
      }
   },
   {
      $group: {
         _id: {
            employee: "$_id.employee",
            year: "$_id.year",
            month: "$_id.month"
         },
         totalforMonth: { $sum: "$totalHrPerDay" },
         days: { $push: "$$ROOT" }
      }
   },
   { $group: { _id: "$_id.employee", data: { $push: "$$ROOT" } } },
   {
      $project: {
         _id: 0,
         employee: "$_id",
         months: {
            $map: {
               input: "$data",
               as: "month",
               in: {
                  number: "$$month._id.month",
                  totalforMonth: "$$month.totalforMonth",
                  days: {
                     $map: {
                        input: "$$month.days",
                        as: "day",
                        in: {
                           day: "$$day._id.day",
                           totalHr: "$$day.totalHrPerDay"
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/T3Tda0Ae6iG)

I also tried with `$facet` but it was getting to complicated.

Comment: thx for the quick answer, looks it works but now i have other issue
i would like it will be group nested means for each employee we set the months and for each months we set the dates. this is could work here?